# Error CS1061 'Mesh' does not contain a definition for 'GetTriangleStrip'

Tags: c#, unity3d

Hola al actualizar mi código de Unity 3.4 a Unity 5.3 me muestra el siguiente error:

> Error  CS1061  'Mesh' does not contain a definition for 'GetTriangleStrip' and 
>       no extension method 'GetTriangleStrip' accepting a first argument of type 'Mesh' 
>       could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

El código en cuestión es el siguiente:

```
int[]  inputtriangles = combine.mesh.GetTriangleStrip(combine.subMeshIndex);
for (int i=0;i<inputtriangles.Length;i++)
{
    triangles[i+triangleOffset] = inputtriangles[i] + vertexOffset;
}
triangleOffset += inputtriangles.Length;
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usted puede tratar lo siguiente:

Cambiar donde aparece `GetTriangleStrip(...)` por `GetTriangles(...)`

```
int[]  inputtriangles = combine.mesh.GetTriangles(combine.subMeshIndex);

for (int i = 0; i < inputtriangles.Length; i++){

    triangles[i+triangleOffset] = inputtriangles[i] + vertexOffset;
}

triangleOffset += inputtriangles.Length;
```

P.D: si en algun lugar usa tambien `SetTriangleStrip(...)` puede sustituir por `SetTriangles(...)`

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.GetTriangles.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.SetTriangles.html

Comment: Gracias, pero no me funciona :/

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro sigue obteniendo el mismo error?

Comment: Lo resolví! http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.GetTriangles.html Favor de actualizar la respuesta para daros la aceptación.

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro la respuesta ya fue actualizada

Comment: no sabia que estabas diciendo, pues los enlaces los habia puesto antes de ver tu comentario en el cual muestras un link igual al que yo puse, pero ahora que veo la edicion creo que quizas no te funciono porque tuve un error al poner GetTriangle pues tambien borre la S de Strip, al estar usando el camelCase se me olvido de volver a ponerla en minusculas, y como el cambio es basicamente borrar el Strip para que funcione, me salio ese error que bueno que lo vieras y lo corrigieras, que pena que SO no tenga un ide integrado jaja Saludos